# Understanding a proof about the form of continuous linear functionals on L(X,Y)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, topological-vector-spaces

I found a proof in a book and can't see how an inequality holds.

From (J. Lindenstrauss, L. Tzafriri; Classical Banach spaces 1: sequence spaces; page 31 proposition 1.e.3):

> Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and put on $L(X,Y)$ the topology $\tau$ on uniform convergence on compact sets in $X$. (Topology generated by the seminorms $||T||_K := sup\{||Tx|| , x \in K\}$). Then, the continuous linear functionals on $(L(X,Y),\tau)$ all consist of the form 
>   $$\varphi(T) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} y'_i(Tx_i), \quad (x_i) \subset X \quad y'_i \subset Y' \quad \sum\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} ||x_i||||y'_i|| < \infty$$
>   ***Proof.*** Assume that $\varphi$ has such a representation. We may clearly assume that $x_i \neq 0$. Let {$\eta_i$} be a sequence of positive scalars tending to $\infty$ so that $\sum\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \eta_i ||x_i||||y'_i|| = C < \infty$. Put $K=\{ \frac{x_i}{||x_i|| \eta_i}\} \cup \{0\}$. Then K is compact and 
>   $$|\varphi(T)| \leq \sum\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} ||y'_i|| ||x_i|| c_i ||T\left(\frac{x_i}{||x_i||c_i}\right)|| \leq C ||T||_K$$

note that this is just the first half of the poof.

My problem now is, that I can't see how the last inequality holds. It's clear that $$ \sum\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} ||y'_i|| ||x_i|| c_i ||T\left(\frac{x_i}{||x_i||c_i}\right)|| = C\sum\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} ||T\left(\frac{x_i}{||x_i||c_i}\right)|| $$ 
but at this point $\sum\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} ||T\left(\frac{x_i}{||x_i||c_i}\right)||$ needs to be smaller than $||T||_K$ . Which I guess is not the case as the supremum could be any of the summands. I can't even see how this is always convergent. Like if $c_i = i$ and $T(\frac{x_i}{||x_i||}) \geq 1$ .

I was too wondering if the proof ( in case its correct ) could be done using the operator norm instead of these seminorms. Then could we just prove it without mentioning the topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring one of the assumptions and going for too big an estimate.

You have 
$$
\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|y'_i\| \,\|x_i\| c_i\, \left\|T\left(\frac{x_i}{||x_i||c_i}\right)\right\| \leq\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|y'_i\| \,\|x_i\| c_i\, \|T\|_K=C\,\|T\|_K. 
$$
And yes, the same argument would work for the operator norm, since it is the case where $K$ is the unit ball. Being continuous in operator norm is easier, so I don't see what you expect from "not mentioning" the topology. And the converse would not work, as not every bounded functional is of the form mentioned; that's where they likely use that $K$ is compact.